# How to get output from Nagios in a file

Tags: linux, nagios

I have configured Nagios monitoring tool for a linux server m/c to monitor another linux host m/c(till now I am monitoring a single m/c only). I have followed the official documentation and installed nagios server on server side and NRPE daemon on client side. As per documentation the nagios is working successfully and maintaining its periodic checks for all the services that I have made it to monitor and also installed some additional plugins too.

But I want to know the procedure how to get output of the monitoring hostory in a particular file in a proper format. As I have not installed the web interface through Apache, yet is there any solution for my problem

Following is the log file I am getting for nagios monitoring:

```
[1349064000] LOG ROTATION: DAILY
[1349064000] LOG VERSION: 2.0
[1349064000] CURRENT HOST STATE: localhost;UP;HARD;1;PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.03 ms
[1349064000] CURRENT HOST STATE: remotehost;UP;HARD;1;PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.17 ms
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: localhost;Current Load;OK;HARD;1;OK - load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: localhost;Current Users;OK;HARD;1;USERS OK - 7 users currently logged in
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: localhost;HTTP;OK;HARD;1;HTTP OK HTTP/1.1 200 OK - 1889 bytes in 0.001 seconds
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: localhost;PING;OK;HARD;1;PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.04 ms
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: localhost;Root Partition;CRITICAL;HARD;100;DISK CRITICAL - free space: / 108 MB (1% inode=61%):
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: localhost;SSH;OK;HARD;1;SSH OK - OpenSSH_5.1 (protocol 2.0)
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: localhost;Swap Usage;OK;HARD;1;SWAP OK - 97% free (841 MB out of 870 MB)
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: localhost;Total Processes;OK;HARD;1;PROCS OK: 79 processes with STATE = RSZDT
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: remotehost;CPU Load;OK;HARD;1;OK - load average: 0.08, 0.02, 0.01
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: remotehost;Current Users;WARNING;HARD;3;USERS WARNING - 3 users currently logged in
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: remotehost;File Size;WARNING;HARD;3;WARN: /home/new/ctags.1p has size 13864 Byte. Warn at 13000. :
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: remotehost;Swap Usage;OK;HARD;1;SWAP OK - 100% free (869 MB out of 870 MB)
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: remotehost;Total Processes;OK;HARD;1;PROCS OK: 106 processes
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: remotehost;Zombie Processes;OK;HARD;1;PROCS OK: 0 processes with STATE = Z
[1349064028] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: nagiosadmin;remotehost;Current Users;WARNING;notify-service-by-email;USERS WARNING - 3 users currently logged in
[1349064988] Auto-save of retention data completed successfully.
[1349065258] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: nagiosadmin;remotehost;File Size;WARNING;notify-service-by-email;WARN: /home/new/ctags.1p has size 13864 Byte. Warn at 13000. :
[1349065938] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: nagiosadmin;localhost;Root Partition;CRITICAL;notify-service-by-email;DISK CRITICAL - free space: / 109 MB (1% inode=61%):
[1349067628] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: nagiosadmin;remotehost;Current Users;WARNING;notify-service-by-email;USERS WARNING - 3 users currently logged in
[1349068588] Auto-save of retention data completed successfully.
[1349068858] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: nagiosadmin;remotehost;File Size;WARNING;notify-service-by-email;WARN: /home/new/ctags.1p has size 13864 Byte. Warn at 13000. :
[1349069538] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: nagiosadmin;localhost;Root Partition;CRITICAL;notify-service-by-email;DISK CRITICAL - free space: / 109 MB (1% inode=61%)
```

Tell me please if I am wrong at something regarding this.
If any more nagios info is required for this problem, let me know I will share that surely.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What i gather from here, is that you are getting all the info on the console. However, you want them to be printed in a text file with a proper format. Is my understanding correct? If so, kindly tell us, how do you run this one ? Do you feed any command to the terminal or you just start and stop the service like WAS ?

Comment: yes I am getting all this from a log file generated in the nagios folder. Yes you are right that I want the output in a file so that it shows atleast the time when nagios is fetching the output from the services of monitored m/c. Nagios is made to start-up during system boot and its service can just be started using 'service start' and 'service stop'.

Answer (score 1):

First let me tell you that i am extremely sorry for not answering your question as i was a little busy these last few days.

Here I am going to provide you two answers to your question .

**First Answer :(Flat and non innovative)**:

```
!/bin/sh
#
# Log file pattern detector plugin for Nagios
#
# Usage: ./check_log <log_file> <old_log_file> <pattern>
#
# Description:
#
# This plugin will scan a log file (specified by the <log_file> option)
# for a specific pattern (specified by the <pattern> option).  Successive
# calls to the plugin script will only report *new* pattern matches in the
# log file, since an copy of the log file from the previous run is saved
# to <old_log_file>.
#
# Output:
#
# On the first run of the plugin, it will return an OK state with a message
# of "Log check data initialized".  On successive runs, it will return an OK
# state if *no* pattern matches have been found in the *difference* between the
# log file and the older copy of the log file.  If the plugin detects any 
# pattern matches in the log diff, it will return a CRITICAL state and print
# out a message is the following format: "(x) last_match", where "x" is the
# total number of pattern matches found in the file and "last_match" is the
# last entry in the log file which matches the pattern.
#
# Notes:
#
# If you use this plugin make sure to keep the following in mind:
#
#    1.  The "max_attempts" value for the service should be 1, as this
#        will prevent Nagios from retrying the service check (the
#        next time the check is run it will not produce the same results).
#
#    2.  The "notify_recovery" value for the service should be 0, so that
#        Nagios does not notify you of "recoveries" for the check.  Since
#        pattern matches in the log file will only be reported once and not
#        the next time, there will always be "recoveries" for the service, even
#        though recoveries really don't apply to this type of check.
#
#    3.  You *must* supply a different <old_file_log> for each service that
#        you define to use this plugin script - even if the different services
#        check the same <log_file> for pattern matches.  This is necessary
#        because of the way the script operates.
#
# Examples:
#
# Check for login failures in the syslog...
#
#   check_log /var/log/messages ./check_log.badlogins.old "LOGIN FAILURE"
#
# Check for port scan alerts generated by Psionic's PortSentry software...
#
#   check_log /var/log/message ./check_log.portscan.old "attackalert"
#

# Paths to commands used in this script.  These
# may have to be modified to match your system setup.
# TV: removed PATH restriction. Need to think more about what this means overall
#PATH=""

ECHO="/bin/echo"
GREP="/bin/egrep"
DIFF="/bin/diff"
TAIL="/bin/tail"
CAT="/bin/cat"
RM="/bin/rm"
CHMOD="/bin/chmod"
TOUCH="/bin/touch"

PROGNAME=`/bin/basename $0`
PROGPATH=`echo $0 | sed -e 's,[\\/][^\\/][^\\/]*$,,'`
REVISION="@NP_VERSION@"

. $PROGPATH/utils.sh

print_usage() {
echo "Usage: $PROGNAME -F logfile -O oldlog -q query"
echo "Usage: $PROGNAME --help"
echo "Usage: $PROGNAME --version"
}

print_help() {
print_revision $PROGNAME $REVISION
echo ""
print_usage
echo ""
echo "Log file pattern detector plugin for Nagios"
echo ""
support
}

# Make sure the correct number of command line
# arguments have been supplied

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
print_usage
exit $STATE_UNKNOWN
fi

# Grab the command line arguments

#logfile=$1
#oldlog=$2
#query=$3
exitstatus=$STATE_WARNING #default
while test -n "$1"; do
case "$1" in
    --help)
        print_help
        exit $STATE_OK
        ;;
    -h)
        print_help
        exit $STATE_OK
        ;;
    --version)
        print_revision $PROGNAME $REVISION
        exit $STATE_OK
        ;;
    -V)
        print_revision $PROGNAME $REVISION
        exit $STATE_OK
        ;;
    --filename)
        logfile=$2
        shift
        ;;
    -F)
        logfile=$2
        shift
        ;;
    --oldlog)
        oldlog=$2
        shift
        ;;
    -O)
        oldlog=$2
        shift
        ;;
    --query)
        query=$2
        shift
        ;;
    -q)
        query=$2
        shift
        ;;
    -x)
        exitstatus=$2
        shift
        ;;
    --exitstatus)
        exitstatus=$2
        shift
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Unknown argument: $1"
        print_usage
        exit $STATE_UNKNOWN
        ;;
esac
shift
done

# If the source log file doesn't exist, exit

if [ ! -e $logfile ]; then
$ECHO "Log check error: Log file $logfile does not exist!\n"
exit $STATE_UNKNOWN
elif [ ! -r $logfile ] ; then
$ECHO "Log check error: Log file $logfile is not readable!\n"
exit $STATE_UNKNOWN
fi

# If the old log file doesn't exist, this must be the first time
# we're running this test, so copy the original log file over to
# the old diff file and exit

if [ ! -e $oldlog ]; then
$CAT $logfile > $oldlog
$ECHO "Log check data initialized...\n"
exit $STATE_OK
fi

# The old log file exists, so compare it to the original log now

# The temporary file that the script should use while
# processing the log file.
if [ -x /bin/mktemp ]; then
tempdiff=`/bin/mktemp /tmp/check_log.XXXXXXXXXX`
else
tempdiff=`/bin/date '+%H%M%S'`
tempdiff="/tmp/check_log.${tempdiff}"
$TOUCH $tempdiff
$CHMOD 600 $tempdiff
fi

$DIFF $logfile $oldlog | $GREP -v "^>" > $tempdiff

# Count the number of matching log entries we have
count=`$GREP -c "$query" $tempdiff`

# Get the last matching entry in the diff file
lastentry=`$GREP "$query" $tempdiff | $TAIL -1`

$RM -f $tempdiff
$CAT $logfile > $oldlog

if [ "$count" = "0" ]; then # no matches, exit with no error
$ECHO "Log check ok - 0 pattern matches found\n"
exitstatus=$STATE_OK
else # Print total matche count and the last entry we found
$ECHO "($count) $lastentry"
exitstatus=$STATE_CRITICAL
fi

exit $exitstatus
```

**But be warned**, I have not run this one, so if it shows some errors, you will have to modify them on your own.

you have to add this line  in commands.cfg

```
define command{
      command_name    check_log
      command_line    $USER1$/check_log -F $CURRENTLOG -O $OLDLOG -q $PATTERN

}
```

Define the service in localhost.cfg

```
define service{

    use  local-service           ; Inherit default values from a template
    host_name      localhost
    service_description   check_log
    check_command check_log!/var/log/secure!/usr/local/nagios/libexec/secure.my!"Failed password"
 }
```

**Second Answer:(A little innovative) :**

As far as i know, the log file for nagios is kept in the following place :
`/var/log/httpd/access_log`

Now your log file like every log will contain time stamp information.So here we need to record the system time when the server is started. From my experience i can say that when we start WAS it spawns a java.exe process. I don't know what it is called in Nagios. Let us consider it is LNT.exe. So we need to find the spawn time for LNT.exe.

Start the server now, logs will be generated. Now you need to read the logs in the log file 
only after this time to see only the current logs.

First, get the id of the process : (`ps -ef LNT.exe`) and store it in a variable such as `processID`.
Then do this: `ls -ld /proc/${processID}` and store the time in variable `startedTime`

Now you have to read the file line by line and you have to compare the time you get with the `startedTime`. If `startedTime` > `timeRead`, then you have got to take that point as the benchmark and then you have to start reading the file from that location.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the kind and interesting answer, i wil try this and then reply back to u if any issues occur.

Comment: Sure, u r welcome mate